# Using the datetime module in python I need to sort the amount column in date order

Tags: python, csv, sorting

I have a small csv file that tracks bets, I need to produce the bets in date order when requested by a user. A sample of the csv is as seen below, year = [2], month = [3], day = [4]:

```
Aintree, Red Rum,2017,5,12,11.58, won
Aintree, Hurricane Fly,2017,5,12,11.58, won
Aintree, Murder,2017,5,12,5, lost 
Ayr, Corbiere,2016,11,3,25, lost
```

(bets = [5])

I have found a way to join the dates column but cannot sort it by date order.

For the homework assignment I cannot use Pandas. Please can you help me sort the issue of converting the new row to a date. Thanks in advance.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

def get_date():

    result=[]

    with open('results.csv', 'r') as csvFilein:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFilein)
        with open('resultscopy.csv', 'w') as csvFileout:
            writer = csv.writer(csvFileout)


            rows = []
            all = []

            for rows in reader:
                new_row = [''.join([rows[2], rows[3], rows[4]])] + rows[7:]
                writer.writerows(all)
                rows.append(all)
                all.append(rows)
                date = datetime.strptime(' 2017 01 11', '%Y %m %d')
                result = str(new_row) + str(rows[5])

                print(date)

            csvFilein.close()

get_date()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the dates to `datetime.datetime` objects, and then sort using the `datetime` object as the key:

```
import datetime, csv
data = [[*i[:2], datetime.datetime(*map(int, i[2:5])), *i[5:]] for i in csv.reader(open('test_csv.csv'))]
result = sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[2])
```

Output:

```
[['Ayr', ' Corbiere', datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 3, 0, 0), '25', ' lost'], ['Aintree', ' Red Rum', datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 12, 0, 0), '11.58', ' won'], ['Aintree', ' Hurricane Fly', datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 12, 0, 0), '11.58', ' won'], ['Aintree', ' Murder', datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 12, 0, 0), '5', ' lost']]
```

Edit: retrieving the date and amount:

```
new_data = [i[2:-1] for i in result]
```

Output:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 3, 0, 0), '25'], [datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 12, 0, 0), '11.58'], [datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 12, 0, 0), '11.58'], [datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 12, 0, 0), '5']]
```

Edit 1: formatting the `datetime` result as a string:

```
new_result = [[f'{a.day}/{a.month}/{a.year}', b] for a, b in new_data]
```

Output:

```
[['3/11/2016', '25'], ['12/5/2017', '11.58'], ['12/5/2017', '11.58'], ['12/5/2017', '5']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ajax! Great help and a lot cleaner than my original way.

Comment: Ajax how would I alter the code to only print the date and amount in columns side by side?

Comment: @JackBennett Glad to help!

Comment: sorry to keep coming back but is there anyway to remove the datetime.date and special chars from the output? I've tried to use replace('[]', '') but it doesn'y seem to work. Any advice?

Comment: @JackBennett No problem. What should the output look like? Should the date be formatted as a single string, or each of its attributes added to the list as elements?

Comment: I've posted the question again here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650275/without-using-pandas-i-need-to-remove-certain-characters-from-my-list-output it has the desired output included and the one line of progress i've made

Comment: @JackBennett Glad to help!