# Without using pandas I need to remove certain characters from my list output

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I want to print the date on the left in date order with the amount to the right, however with my current code it includes the special characters and datetime.date with the output. My desired output is:

dd/mm/yyyy   'amount'

however current output is as below:

[datetime.date(2016, 6, 22), ' 52.52']

[datetime.date(2016, 10, 2), ' 65.75']

[datetime.date(2016, 11, 1), ' 15.00']

[datetime.date(2016, 11, 3), ' 25.00']

[datetime.date(2016, 11, 3), ' 25.00']

Can anyone help me to remove the special characters and datetime.date, it is for an assignment so I cannot use pandas. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, date 


def betdate():
    data = [[*i[:2], datetime.strftime(*map(int, i[2:5])), *i[5:]] for i in 
csv.reader(open('results.csv'))]
    result = sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[2])
    new_data = [i[2:-1] for i in result]


    print('\n'.join(map(str, new_data)))

betdate()
```

Comment: Read about [datetime.datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime)

Comment: I keep getting this AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strftime' ?

Comment: *"AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strftime' "*: [Edit] your Question and show your `import ...` and `strftime` statement.